# Calculate Total wages of all the Employees Based on Last Updated Sequence Number

Tags: sql, sql-server

consider a table

```
employee id    report_year  report_quarter  sequencenumber quarter1_wage quarter2_wage 
101                2015       1              1              1000           0
101                2015       1              2              2000           0
102                2016       2              1              3000           0
102                2016       2              2               0            4000
```

The Result of the query must be

```
      Total wages

         6000
```

As in 2015 Employee id 101 with Highest sequence number 2 has 2000 comes under quarter1 as report _quarter is indicating it is 1 need to add take this value and add to the

2016 Employee id 102 with highest sequence number 2 has 4000(quarter2_wage) 
as report _quarter is indicating it is 2

Comment: "Hint"??  Is this some sort of exam question or homework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(quarter1_wage )+SUM(quarter2_wage) AS total
,MAX(sequencenumber)
,report_year
FROM table 
GROUP BY report_year
```

Comment: could you please consider adding some explanations, so the OP actually understands what happens here?

Comment: Need to select only the indicated quarter with the highest sequence number

Answer (score 0):

Use with Ties and Order by to get only the Highest sequence Numbers by EmployeeId and then Sum that Derived Table

```
 Select SUM(quarter1_wage )+SUM(quarter2_wage) AS total from (
    Select Top 1 with Ties * from table 
       ORDER BY row_number() over (partition by employee_id order by sequencenumber desc)) as DerivedTable
```